# "Show More" Button after X buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68ksyfhj/1/) and this is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".keywordsdiv" ).each(function(){
      $(this).children(".keywords").eq(3).after('<a href="" id="playtrailershowmorebuttons">....Show More</a>');//add a unique id to link
      $(this).children(".keywords:gt(2)" ).addClass('hide');
  });
});

$(document).on('click','a#playtrailershowmorebuttons',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  $(this).parent().children('button.keywords').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="keywordsdiv">
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">CYZ</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">RGRDFS</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">FVFVV</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">FESF</button></a>
</div>

<div class="keywordsdiv">
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">CYZ</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">RGRDFS</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">FVFVV</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">FESF</button></a>
</div>
```

I want the script to display `Show More` button, if there are more than 3 buttons with `keywords` class in a `div` with class `keywordsdiv`, as you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36d479bz/)

This code works, If i remove the `<a></a>` tags in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do with `find()` instead of `children()` .because `keywords` not direct children of the div .

[**Updated jsfiddle old**](https://jsfiddle.net/36d479bz/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".keywordsdiv").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".keywords").eq(3).after('<a href="" id="playtrailershowmorebuttons">....Show More</a>'); //add a unique id to link
    $(this).find(".keywords:gt(2)").addClass('hide');
  });
});

$(document).on('click', 'a#playtrailershowmorebuttons', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  $(this).parent().children('button.keywords').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="keywordsdiv">
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">CYZ</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">RGRDFS</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">FVFVV</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">FESF</button></a>
</div>

<div class="keywordsdiv">
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">CYZ</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">RGRDFS</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">FVFVV</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">FESF</button></a>
</div>
```

**Updated**

[**Updated fiddle with latest**](https://jsfiddle.net/36d479bz/3/)

1. `keywordsdiv` not a `direct` parent of the `button` so use with [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjqZqrmIvVAhXJNo8KHfx5BLAQFgi-ATAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AFQjCNGkhpVv76EWvWWYjEID4qvdUghHMQ) and mention the parent class
2. And to apppend `showmore` element with `class name` instead of `id` .And do with click with in a `classname`
3. And remove the `classname` only with same classname contains element.its means `find('.hide').removeClass('hide')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".keywordsdiv" ).each(function(){
      $(this).find(".keywords").eq(3).after('<a href="" class="playtrailershowmorebuttons">....Show More</a>');//add a unique id to link
      $(this).find(".keywords:gt(2)" ).addClass('hide');
  });
});

$(document).on('click','.playtrailershowmorebuttons',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.keywordsdiv').find('.hide').removeClass('hide');
  $(this).addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="keywordsdiv">
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>

</div>

<div class="keywordsdiv">
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>
<a href="#"><button class="keywords">ABC</button></a>


</div>
```

Comment: Why it shows only 1 button when someone clicks `show more`? https://jsfiddle.net/36d479bz/2/

Answer (score 2):

Assign class keywords to links, not buttons:

```
<a class="keywords" href="#"><button>ABC</button></a>
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/68ksyfhj/10/

Comment: in your fiddle you forgot to assign a class keywordsdiv to divs. Add that as in the poster's question

Comment: That's what he wanted, there is a show more button after three butons

Comment: Bro, I want to show the buttons, when someone clicks on `show more` link

Comment: Sorry, replace your click handler with this one:$(document).on('click','a#playtrailershowmorebuttons',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  $('.keywords').removeClass('hide');
});

Comment: Wait a bit, must sort out the line in which button is located, this shows all

Comment: $(document).on('click','a#playtrailershowmorebuttons',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  $(this).parent().children('.keywords').removeClass('hide');
});

Comment: Sorry but the other answer is better